# Defining a command and its starred version with different number of arguments

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, starred-version, vector

I want to create the commands:

`$\vecbi*{A}{s}$` and `$\vecbi{A}$`

To write bold vectors in my text.

However, I have tried the following code, but I am still stucked without a solution.

```
\makeatletter
\def\vecbi#1#2{\@ifstar\vecbiu\vecbin}
\def\vecbiu#1#2{\boldsymbol{#1}_{\text{#2}}}
\def\vecbin#1{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\vecbi#1#2{\@ifstar\vecbiu\vecbin}
\def\vecbiu#1#2{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}_{\text{#2}}}}
\def\vecbin#1{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\vecbi*{A}{s} * \vecbi{A}$

\vspace{2cm}

\lipsum[21]

\end{document}
```

The solution could also be without the starred version, something like

`$\vecbi{A}{s}$` and `$\vecbi{A}$`.

I would be glad if you can help (correct) me.

Comment: Use an optional argument. Why do the rather complicated *starred* business?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command `\vecbi` should be defined *without* arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\vecbi{\@ifstar\vecbiu\vecbin}
\newcommand\vecbiu[2]{\bm{#1}_{\textnormal{#2}}}
\newcommand\vecbin[1]{\bm{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\vecbi*{A}{s} * \vecbi{A}$

\end{document}
```

I have replaced the obsolete `\boldsymbol` with `\bm` and removed `\ensuremath` that only does damages to your own typescript. Instead of `\text`, that doesn't guarantee upright shape, I used `\textnormal`.

[image]

Alternative approaches: optional arguments. The first is what I'd prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vecbi}{om}{%
  \bm{#2}\IfValueT{#1}{_{\textnormal{#1}}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\vecbix}{mg}{
  \bm{#1}\IfValueT{#2}{_{\textnormal{#2}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\vecbi[s]{A} * \vecbi{A}$

$\vecbix{A}{s} * \vecbix{A}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you need to declare the macro with one or two parameters `\vecbi{A}` or `\vecbi{B}{s}`, then you have to say what is the signal of the presence of second parameter. For example the signal is the open `{` used immediately after the first parameter without space between them. Then you can use this:

```
\def\vecbi#1{\def\tmp{#1}\futurelet\next\vecbiA}
\def\vecbiA{\ifx\next\bgroup\expandafter\vecbiu \else \expandafter\vecbin \fi}
\def\vecbiu#1{{\bf\tmp}_{\rm#1}}
\def\vecbin{{\bf\tmp}}

$ \vecbi{A}{s}, \vecbi{B} $
```

This code needn't any package, because it is based only on TeX primitives. Sorry, I didn't use LaTeX-like math-font selectors in this example because I don't use LaTeX. You can replace the body of the macros `\vecbiu` and `\vecbin` as you wish.

EDIT: The common principle, how to implement the macro with zero to nine parameters, `\macro`, `\macro{A}`, `\macro{a}{b}{c}{d}`, etc., follows:

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}

\def\macro{\tmpnum=0 \def\tmp{}\futurelet\next\macroA}
\def\macroA{\ifx\next\bgroup \expandafter\macroB \else \expandafter\macroC \fi}
\def\macroB#1{\advance\tmpnum by1 \addto\tmp{{#1}}\futurelet\next\macroA}
\def\macroC{\csname macro\the\tmpnum\expandafter\endcsname\tmp}
\sdef{macro0}{\message{macro with no parameters}}
\sdef{macro1}#1{\message{macro with one parameter #1}}
\sdef{macro2}#1#2{\message{macro with two parameters #1, #2}}
\sdef{macro3}#1#2#3{\message{macro with three parameters #1, #2, #3}}
\sdef{macro4}#1#2#3#4{\message{macro with four parameters #1, #2, #3, #4}}
\sdef{macro5}#1#2#3#4#5{\message{macro with five parameters #1, #2, #3, #4, #5}}
\sdef{macro6}#1#2#3#4#5#6{\message{macro with six parameters}}
\sdef{macro7}#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\message{macro with seven parameters}}
\sdef{macro8}#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{\message{macro with eight parameters}}
\sdef{macro9}#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{\message{macro with nine parameters}}

\macro{A}{B}, \macro{C}, \macro{D}{E}{F}, \macro.
```

Comment: Honestly, there's no need to always bash LaTeX as being something built on TeX and therefore inferior (in your opinion). You drive a specific kind of car that has a manual transmission; others enjoy a different kind of car that has a semi-automatic flavour, allowing you to mix-and-match.

Comment: @Werner I don't see where this is LaTeX bashing?  @wipet This is not purely based on primitves (`\rm`, `\bf`), but either way +1

Comment: @HenriMenke: You'd have to follow the history, documented to some extent in [wipet's use description](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/51799/wipet)...

Comment: @Werner IMHO, my post isn't critique of LaTeX here. It shows only another solution how to implement the macro with one or two parameters without LaTeX packages. But this solution *works in LaTeX too*. @HenriMenke I know that `\rm` and `\bf` are not primitives but my attempt was to show the principles of one/two parameters macros based only on primitives.

Comment: You'll never convince me that four lines replete with `\futurelet`, `\expandafter` and `\bgroup` are better than the one liner `\NewDocumentCommand{\vecbi}{mg}{...#1...\IfValueT{#2}{...#2...}}`